# How to play video without the full screen mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, video

Is there a way to add video to a view like you would with an image and an image view? I don't want the full screen mode like in the YouTube app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVPlayer from AVFoundation Framework
[AVPlayer Demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

1.Import media player framework- #import

2.Declare Instance variable  MPMoviePlayerController *player;

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
      //you can try other api to get movie file path in ios 8
        NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                         pathForResource:@"Trailer"
                         ofType:@"m4v"];

        player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                  initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
         object:player];

        //—set the size of the movie view and then add it to the View window—
        player.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300);    
        [self.view addSubview:player.view];

        //—play movie—
        [player play];

        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    //—called when the movie is done playing—
    - (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [aNotification object];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         removeObserver:self
         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
         object:moviePlayer];   
        [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];

    }

//-(NSString *)path
//{
//    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, //NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//    NSString *documentDir=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
//    return [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Trailer.m4v"];
//}
```